# Ext.grid.plugin.RowExpander.setCmp(): The 'rowBodyTpl' config is required and is not defined (ExtJS 7.3x)

Tags: javascript, extjs

I am trying to use the RowExpander plugin, and I am getting the error

***app.js?_dc=1622045752220:5338 [E] Ext.grid.plugin.RowExpander.setCmp(): The 'rowBodyTpl' config is required and is not defined.***

I have tried the following two scenarios to define the rowBodyTpl and the error still occurs. Anyone have any ideas?

Implementation one I added the itemConfig as the [example rowExpander in sencha docs](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.3.1/modern/Ext.grid.plugin.RowExpander.html)

```js
{
    xtype: 'gridcolumn',
    store: 'Accounts',
    plugins: {
        rowexpander: true,
    },
    itemConfig: {
        body: {
            tpl: '<img height="100" src="http://www.sencha.com/assets/images/sencha-//avatar-64x64.png"/>'
        }
    }
}
```

My second attempt I added the rowbody tpl to the gridcolumn itself and still get the error above..

```js
{
    xtype: 'gridcolumn',
    store: 'Accounts',
    plugins: {
        rowexpander: true,
    },
    rowBodyTpl: null
    enter code here
}
```

Comment: What I do not understand here is why you add the plugin to a column and not to the grid like in the linked example (Sencha docs). You can also create a [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor) in order to reproduce the problem.

Comment: I put the plugin in the wrong place, I forgot to add it into the grid in my question, but still the code wasn't working with just using the rowBodyTpl: null or rowBodyTpl: '<p>tag</p>'. We figured out we needed the actual rowBodyTpl: new Ext.XTemplate(
    '<p>text</p>'
)

Sorry for the late response, but yes I rewrote the code instead of pasting it straight from what we had worked on and miss-placed it.

Comment: The docs doesn't include an example for classic toolkit. Anybody knows how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

For Classic Toolkit.

```
plugins: {
   rowexpander: {
      rowBodyTpl: new Ext.XTemplate( '<p>text</p>' )
   }
},
```